# How to convert List of Object into List of Strings

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist

**I'm trying to Convert List of Object into List of Strings**

My List of Custom Object is like this

> convertedData
>   { rawMaterialId: "3411", batchNumber: "166,465,963,962,785", 
>   location: "hhh,ooo,hhh,uio,pop", quantity: "900,302,560,650,989" }

I'm trying to convert this JSON object into List of Strings

It should look like this,

> List[
>    "3411" ,"166" ,"465" ,"963" ,"hhh","ooo","pop","900","302","560"]

**I tried with below code**

```
String[] array = new String[convertedData.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for (Object value : convertedData) {
      array[index] = (String) value;
      index++;
    }
```

Any suggestions and correction welcomed.Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "different output", what exactly is this output? The problem with your code is probably that you aren't splitting anything and you should be using a `List` rather than an array since you don't know how many tokens you have.

Comment: yes, that might be a reason. can you please suggest some corrections to code.

Comment: Can *you* please edit into your question what "different output" you are getting?

Comment: Why not start by using a JSON parser to parse the JSON into something more managable

Comment: I'm getting output like this:    `[Ljava.lang.String;@7dcc5de4`

Comment: What is the declared type of `convertedData`?  How was it populated?

Comment: @UllasSharma That's what printing an array looks like by default. If you want to print the contents in a readable format, use `Arrays.toString(array)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split the converted data.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object value : convertedData) {
    if (value instanceof String) {
        String str = (String) value;
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
    }
}
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object value : convertedData) {
        String[] wordList = ((String) value).split(",");
        for (String val : wordList) {
            list.add(val);
        }
    }

    String[] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: The array might not have enough space; a `List` should be used here instead.

Comment: I meant to add the individual tokens to (i.e. to replace the `array` variable). Using an array for `String.split` is perfectly fine, since it does return one after all.

Comment: `Arrays.asList((String) value).split(","))` you cannot apply `split()` to a `List<String>`